# Redash - Change Postgres connection port

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, redash

Is it possible to change the port Redash connects to Postgres?

I had initially set-up Redash successfully and connected to Postgres, but after a few days, it was impossible to start Postgres on port 5432. I even tried reinstalling but it forcefully sets the port to 5433. I have tried to change the port to 5433 on redash/query_runner/pg.py but there is no change.

How can I change the port flask listens to, to 5433 or any other for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

The file 'query_runner/pg.py' is designed to connnect remote database like mysql.py, oracle.py and so on. It's not the backend database saving users' infomation. So you should try to change the value like

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get(
"REDASH_DATABASE_URL", os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL", "postgresql:///postgres"))
```

It is in 'redash/settings/__init__.py', but I am sorry that I don't know the detail about how to change it.